# Google Cloud Function Error - res.setHeader is not a function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run first example from  [Cloud Functions Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart#windows).
I created my function, and literally copied and pasted example from docs.

**Correction**: I took example code from here:
https://api.ai/docs/getting-started/basic-fulfillment-conversation

First error I received was;

> res.setHeader is not a function

Then I tried to use another function to set header like;

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
```

But this gives me same error as well. 
Here is my following code;

```
/**
 * Cloud Function.
 *
 * @param {object} event The Cloud Functions event.
 * @param {function} callback The callback function.
 */
exports.helloHttp = function helloHttp(req, res) {
    response = "This is a sample response from your webhook!" //Default response from the webhook to show it's working

    // res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); //Requires application/json MIME type
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    //"speech" is the spoken version of the response, "displayText" is the visual version
    res.send(JSON.stringify({
        "speech": response,
        "displayText": response        
    }));
};
```

And following how it appears at test console;

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my dummy mistake there I had to choose HTTP trigger on creating. 
It works fine now.

[image]